# firebase Stripe API failing on first payment process

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have successfully integrated stripe and firebase, using the `Run Subscription Payments with Stripe`.

Here's the flow:

When I click register, it brings me to the Stripe Page, using this function:

```
  export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  
      const checkoutSessionRef =  firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(userID)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: price,
        success_url: "https://xxx/successPage",
        cancel_url: "https://xxx/signin",
    });
      // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
            (await checkoutSessionRef).onSnapshot(function (snap) {
              const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
              if (error) {
              console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
            }
            if (sessionId) {

            //live key
            const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_livekeyxxxx');
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId})
            console.log("logged stripe")
          }
      });
    }
```

If successful, it goes to to my `SuccessPage`, which just checks if the subscriptions collection was created in firebase or not.

so what happens is, if the payment is successful, it will just render `/clients` route, and if it isn't, it will redirect to `createCheckoutSession` function, which goes back to allow the customer to pay again. So when I enter the payment details on Stripe, SOMETIMES, it goes to clients and adds the subscription, and SOMETIMES, it redirects to the Stripe page, and makes me enter ti again, in which then it works.

is this a bug in my code, or is firebase and stripe just finicky?

Comment: There's a lot going on here with nested layers of firestore calls that are difficult to read. Can you provide a clear sequence of what you expect to happen and what actually happens? I'd suggest you try trimming you code to *only* the happy path of that you're trying to achieve to understand where things might be going awry. You need to narrow down where in your code unexpected behaviour happens, then ask specifically about that part, rather than your entire user flow.

Comment: Separately, I see you referring to `window.Stripe` and `stripe.redirectToCheckout` in what looks like server-side code. Not that Stripe.js and `redirectToCheckout` are meant to be run on the client and trigger a client-side redirect. Perhaps I've misread the firebase code, though.

Comment: @NolanH i've updated my question to show it a little easier... I understand what you are saying, but even so, would that be making it fail sometimes?

Comment: What are you using to determine the action following redirect to the success page? This would seem to be in the control of your application. I worry about what you're checking, and whether you could accidentally have your customer paying twice. You should not see customers redirected to the success page unless creating the subscription was successful. How do you know if this worked or not?

Comment: @NolanH my code is set up so that it looks in firestore to see if the subscription collection has been created, if it has, allow entry to the app. The subscirption collection is only created when a payment is processed successfully, and then a document with the uid is created. my code checks for that, and if there is no entries, then it redirects them back to checkout, because it means the user never actually paid. I've confirmed this working in Stripe dashboard as well

Comment: This would be surprising. You should not expect a customer to be redirected to your success URL unless the Checkout session was completed successfully.

Comment: the checkout session is completed successfully, but the subscription does not get created sometimes. that is where the problem lies. So stripe is considering it successful becasue it created the checkout session collection, but did not create the subscriptions one, whcih is wehre i come in and check it in what i call the success page

Comment: That shouldn't happen. If you're seeing a Checkout session with `mode=subscription` succeed without creating a subscription, I would recommend contacting support with exact checkout session ID examples to have them help you investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be losing your reference to your customer when they arrive at the success page, making it so that you can't inspect their new subscription.

Beyond options like authenticated sessions to load your user profile, you could consider setting up your success page to [receive the Session ID](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url), and optionally include your own customer ID. You should of course still ensure your customer is authenticated before showing any personal information, but this might help you to load the data.

**Update**: once you have a successful session, you can retrieve it from the API (or inspect your webhook data) to look at the `subscription` attribute ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-subscription)) to find the created subscription id.